# Expand v-btn-toggle to 100% width of container

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify and a v-btn-toggle.  I'd like to have the buttons expand to 100% of the container they are in.  I figure there's a way to do this using aspects of vuetify instead of custom css, but I can't figure it out if so.  Is there a vuetify way to do this?

```
<v-btn-toggle v-model="type" mandatory tile color="primary">
  <v-btn value="text">Note</v-btn>
  <v-btn value="list">List</v-btn>
  <v-btn value="upload">Upload</v-btn>
</v-btn-toggle>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use d-flex

```
<v-btn-toggle v-model="type" mandatory tile color="primary" class="d-flex flex-row">
  <v-btn value="text" class="flex-grow-1">Note</v-btn>
  <v-btn value="list" class="flex-grow-1">List</v-btn>
  <v-btn value="upload" class="flex-grow-1">Upload</v-btn>
</v-btn-toggle>
```